maximum of sine values
for $\alpha \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, define sequence $\theta_n$ as follows:
$\theta_1=0$
$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n+\alpha$ if $\theta_n \le \frac{\pi}{2}$
$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n-\alpha$ if $\theta_n \gt \frac{\pi}{2}$.
define sequence $x_n$ as follows:
$x_1=0, x_{n+1}=x_n + \frac{\sin \theta_{n+1}}{2^{n-1}}$

Prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n$ converges
and  2. find $\alpha$ that maximizes $\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n$.

I solved problem 1,
$\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\sin \theta_n}{2^{n-2}}$ absolutely converges, so the limit converges, but I can't solve problem 2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If $\alpha>0$, then there is some $k\in\Bbb N$ s. t. $k\alpha\le\frac\pi2$, but $(k+1)\alpha>\frac\pi2$ so, starting from $n=k$, I believe, $\theta_n$ will alternate between those two values.
